# How can I read the value of a custom input component from its parent form component?

Tags: javascript, web-component, stenciljs

I'm a beginner with StencilJS and I'm trying to build a simple login interface. I previously created a custom Input component (which includes some nice features like validation and such) and now I want to reuse it inside a Form component I'm building, basically something like this:

```
<form>
 <my-input type="email" name="email">
 <my-input type="password" name="password">
 <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

From my form component, I need to read the value of my custom input fields from a function that gets executed onSubmit. How can I read such values from the parent form component? Should I emit a custom event within the input component with the value of the input and Listen() to it from the Form component?

Comment: Yes, Events are the most flexible way to go. Note that you can also pass function references in the ``detail`` part of a Custom Event. So your input can send an Event to the Form which in turn executes a function/method on the Input

Comment: If the value is a property using `reflectToAttr`, it can be accessed from the host element `my-input` using `getAttribute()`.