# How to get the value of a custom input component inside a form?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, forms

I wrote a small custom component in react-ts that wraps an `<input />` with some additional functionality, mainly fuzzy searching through a list of options. I am planning to use this inside a form.

However now that I created the component, I can not retrieve its value inside a `<form>`, since it is not a html element and has no `value` attribute that i can read.

I am reading the docs [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html), but it is not helping me. I also tried googling things like "custom input in react form", "get value from custom react component" etc. but could not find any results, although I am sure this should be a pretty straight-forward thing happening to a lot of people. the closest result I could find was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57280894/how-can-i-read-the-value-of-a-custom-input-component-from-its-parent-form-compon) and the answers did not help me at all.

the component:

```
export interface SmartInputProps {
    items: any[],
    itemKey: string
    //[...]
}

export const SmartInput: React.FC<SmartInputProps> = ({
    items,
    itemKey = 'name'
    //[...]
}: SmartInputProps) => {

    // [...]
    // (lots of funcionality)

    return (
        <div>
            <input /*[...]*/ />
            //some more visual stuff, like displaying list of results
        </div>
    );
}
```

And the form I want to use the component in

```
interface Props {
    className?: string
}

export const SearchBar: React.FC<Props> = () => {
    // [...]
    
    return (
        <div className="searchbar-wrapper">
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <SmartInput
                    items={options}
                    itemKey='name' 
                    //[...]
                />
                <input type='submit' value='OK' />
            </form>
        </div>
    );
}
```

I would like to access the current `value` of the `<input />` that is inside `<SmartInput />` in the form.

I tried using hacky ways of getting the value, such as delegating the `onChange` of the `<input />` upwards (as [proposed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64134105/react-how-do-i-get-the-value-of-a-custom-textinput-component)), but that only allows me to get and store the value whenever `onChange` is triggered, not read it at submit-time. This workaround does allow me to use the value at submit-time but I have to handle every single `onChange` first which is sub-optimal.

Comment: "I tried using hacky ways of getting the value, such as delegating the onChange of the <input /> upwards" - seeing as the initial value is sent via the `value` prop,  and that value is updated onChange of your custom input, when would you need to "read it at submit time" - wouldn't it always be the correct value?

I only ask as I use this particular pattern all the time with custom inputs.

Comment: Assuming you're worried about a user entering text into the field and then hitting enter to submit the form, you could use `onKeyUp={e => { e.currentTarget.value}}` instead of `onChange`

Comment: @JohnDetlefs Thanks for your reply, in my mind I was set on evading redundantly calling a function on every input / keystroke (possibly dozens of times) just to use the very last value received. As it seems that doesn't seem to be an issue at all, performance wise. In that case the pattern is probably the most convenient solution and I will stick with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a better solution using [`useRef`](https://react.dev/reference/react/useRef) which is also more elegant.

Using the initial examples:

```
interface Props {
    className?: string
}

export const SearchBar: React.FC<Props> = () => {
    const inputRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null); //<- here
    // [...]
    
    return (
        <div className="searchbar-wrapper">
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <SmartInput
                    items={options}
                    itemKey='name'
                    ref={inputRef}   //<- here
                    //[...]
                />
                <input type='submit' value='OK' />
            </form>
        </div>
    );
}
```

We add a `useRef` with the input type interface to the component. then we pass it to the custom component `<SmartInput />` as a prop.

On the side of the receiving component:

```
export interface SmartInputProps {
    items: any[],
    itemKey: string,
    ref: MutableRefObject<HTMLInputElement> //<- here
    //[...]
}

export const SmartInput: React.FC<SmartInputProps> = ({
    items,
    itemKey = 'name',
    ref, //<- here
    //[...]
}: SmartInputProps) => {

    // [...]
    // (lots of funcionality)

    return (
        <div>
            <input ref={ref} /*<- here*/ /*[...]*/ />
            //some more visual stuff, like displaying list of results
        </div>
    );
}
```

We add the ref to the custom component props and pass it to the `ref` attribute of the vanilla html input field inside our custom component.

No we can query the field state from the root ref object.

e.g. `let fieldValue = inputRef.current.value`.